# Spring + JPA/Hibernate not saving many-to-many mapping

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

**Situation**

I have a `RoleEntity` and a `UserEntity`. A `RoleEntity` contains a list of `UserEntity` and vice-versa, resulting in a `Many-To-Many` relationship.

My `UserEntity`:

```
public class UserEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
    private String lastName;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinTable(name = "uas_user_role",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "uas_user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "uas_role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"uas_user_id", "uas_role_id"})}
    )
    private Set<RoleEntity> roles = new HashSet<>();
...
}
```

My `RoleEntity`:

```
public class RoleEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Set<UserEntity> users;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "uas_role_permission",
        joinColumns
        = @JoinColumn(name = "uas_role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns
        = @JoinColumn(name = "uas_permission_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"uas_role_id", "uas_permission_id"})}
    )
    private Set<PermissionEntity> permissions;
...
}
```

**Goal**

Now I would like to change the mappings by simply update a single entity. For example I want to add a `UserEntity` to a `RoleEntity` with id=1:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Admin_Role",
    "users": [{"id": 1}
    ]
}
```

Saving this `RoleEntity` to it's role repository (`JPARepository.saveAndFlush(Serializable)`), successfully resolves the implied `UserEntity` and is returning the updated `RoleEntity`

```
 {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Admin_Role",
    "users": [{
            "id": 1,
            "username": "admin",
            "firstName": "Administrator",
            "lastName": "Administrator",
            "email": "info@example.com",
        }
    ]
}
```

**Problem**

My test are all passing because I only checked the return value of the save command.
Now I found out when doing a `roleRepository.findOne(1)` after the persisting, I'll receive the following `RoleEntity`:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Admin_Role",
    "users": []
}
```

The `UserEntity` mapping did not get persisted.
Also when setting `spring.jpa.show-sql=true`, I see that only `SELECT` operations are executed during the `saveAndFlush` command.
I only want to create mappings with the and don't want to allow editing of the mapping entity, that's why I've disabled any cascading.

I've expected that with this approach, a mapping gets created. What am I doing wrong?

**Solution**

As *Amer Qarabsa* mentioned:
To create a bidirectional mapping, it needs to be set on both sides. Adding one line after saving an entity already does the trick:

```
@Transactional
public RoleDto updateRole(RoleDto role) {
    RoleEntity roleEntity = roleRepository.findOne(role.getId());
    if (roleEntity==null){
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException();
    }
    final RoleEntity savedRoleEntity = roleRepository.saveAndFlush(roleEntity);
    savedRoleEntity.getUsers().forEach(user -> user.getRoles().add(savedRoleEntity));
    return savedRoleEntity;
}
```

With the `.saveAndFlush(roleEntity)` I'll first update the `RoleEntity` and let JPA resolve the `UserEntity`. After this, I simply set the `RoleEntity` to each `UserEntity` of the role. In my case, I don't need to persist that manually, as the transaction will take care of persisting any unsaved changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well in bidirectional relation its not simple to do this, you cannot take the json and map it to entity so simply, each side of the relation should have a reference to the other side , so in your case you need to take the each userentity inside the role entity and set the role entity of it then save.

Comment: I would have expected Jpa/Hibernate to take care about this, as all necessary information is available. This is not the case then?

Comment: @HerrDerb no, it makes no sense to be handled by jpa , specially if you think about the nullable scenario

Comment: Oh I get it. It's actually quite simple to solve. I'll add the concrete solution to my question. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, adding is easy, but how would I remove a mapping if the new user list has one user removed? This doesn't seem that simple.

Comment: Also when adding the  `@JoinTable` on both sites, It works as expected. But why is this considered bad?

Comment: In every relation there should be an owning entity where the relation will be terminated from it , in you case the entity annotated  with jointable is the one so you should start the removing from there.
for annotating both sides with jointable i think this will result in two junction tables, you can try I am not really sure